# Azure DevOps Clean after pipeline run

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have self-hosted build agents using Azure DevOps. We have the clean flag in the checkout step, however we run out of space sometimes.

**What is the preferred way of cleaning the agents' work directories?**

The problem is, that the clean process is in the beginning of a pipeline, and leaves everything behind. This is even worse if we have two parallel builds. (First clean then clones the repo, then the second cleans and clones the repo, then first build, then there is no space for the second build). Unless the first build is scheduled again, the build outputs stays on the agent.

We tried to schedule a deletion task every day, but it doesn't solve our problems.

We tried to add a script at the end of our `yaml` file that cleans the working dir. Is it recommended?

```
    - powershell: Remove-Item $(Pipeline.Workspace)/** -Force
      displayName: Clean after publish
```

Also it would be great if we could clean up even if the build fails, or someone cancels it midway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `clean` option within the job properties. See the [job definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines).

> ```
> jobs:
> - job:
> ...
>  workspace:  # Workspace options on the agent.
>    clean: string # Which parts of the workspace should be scorched before fetching.  (outputs, resources, all)
> ```

As it would be called before fetching, there will be always space for the new build.

Comment: This does a clean of the workspace **before** your build runs, not after

Answer (score 2):

```yaml
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'clean *'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    Contents: '**/*'
    RemoveDotFiles: true
  condition: always()
```

will clean everything in '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/notClean/**allClean**'.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use `DeleteFiles@1`, like @lionclub. But the implementation is very slow for large repositories.

So, I decided to use PowerShell:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Cleanup source folder'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach { Write-Host $_.FullName ; Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse }'
    failOnStderr: true
    pwsh: true
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

There are variations:

1. Using `failOnStderr` or not
2. Using PowerShell or PowerShell Core (`pwsh: true`)
3. Add separate tasks for `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`
4. Clear complete working folder e.g. by using variable `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
5. Adding `condition: always()` to always clear folder, incl. failed runs

Comment: Would it not be quicker to skip the loop and just run `Remove-Item $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Force -Recurse`

Comment: This is maybe another variation. My version reports progress.
Please note that I reverted your edit and converted it into variation because I think that failed runs should not be cleared by default.